# Compare page items with string in Oracle APEX SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT 'Alle' AS l, 'SAS' AS r FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
     --Montage B
SELECT DISTINCT KPI_VIEW_ID_MONAT.OE AS l, KPI_VIEW_ID_MONAT.OE AS r 
    FROM KPI_VIEW_ID_MONAT
        WHERE KPI_VIEW_ID_MONAT.OE LIKE
           (SELECT CASE  :P46_GEWERKE WHEN 'Montage B' THEN 'N/PN-MA21%'
               ELSE 'N%'
        END
        FROM DUAL
        )
```

I wander what am i doing wrong with comparing the page item "P46_GEWERKE"(Which contains static names) with string 'Montage B'. MY program seems to skip the CASE statement or consider it false all the time and jumps to ELSE statement and executes it.
I am trying to make the program read the first list (GEWERKE) and give it a code according to the string it finds in the list, then pick all the values from the table "KPI_VIEW_ID_MONAT" having the same code and show it in a list called (OE)[snapshot of the two lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZce.png)

Comment: Is `Montage B` the display value **AND** the return value? the page item will be the return value of the selection.

Comment: It is a display-only item, so i guess the display value is the root value if that is what you are asking for. @EJEgyed

Comment: Even if the page item is set to Read Only, each selection will have a Display Value and a Return Value. You will need to make sure that the Return Value of the selected item is what you are using in your query.

Comment: Thank you @EJEgyed!! I managed out to solve the error thanks to your comment :)